# Why vertical-align: middle not working on the image?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Please help me to solve this problem. Images are shown only from the top and I want to show them from the middle of any vertical image.
vertical-align: middle, on the Images in the listings of this page not working.

[Main Page of the Listings](https://business.mds-app.com/)

This is the Code:

```
<div class="carousel-item @if ($key == 0) active @endif">
<a href="{{ url('/details') }}/{{ $business->id }}">
<img src="{{ url('public/pixeladmin/plugins/images/business/' . $img->image . '') }}"
class="d-block w-100 business-images" alt="..."></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use flex on parent node like

```
.parent{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

More about flex box here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout

Answer (score -1):

Here's my favorite website for [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

You can try vertical alignment like this:

```
.parentDiv {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: still not working